# Can I "force_list" more than one parameter in xmltodict?

Tags: python, xmltodict

I am calling a web API in Python, getting data back in XML, converting the response into a dictionary using xmltodict, but for several elements, sometimes I get a dictionary (single element) and sometimes I get a list (multiple elements) in response.

I first started to use "if isinstance(..., dict):" - that could solve my problem but is not so elegant and requires quite some lines of code in my case.
I then found out "force_list" which I think is exactly what I need, but I need to apply it to several elements and I can't find the right syntax - I'm not even sure if that's possible.

## The code I am trying to make work:

response = xmltodict.parse(xml, force_list=({'Child'},{'Brother'}))

With force_list={'Child'} only, the code works as expected.
With the above code, I do not get any error message but when checking the result with the "type" function, I still have dictionaries where I would expect to get lists.
I tried other syntax and got error messages.

Comment: I am facing the same situation in a Python program I am writing.  I really feel uncomfortable with this non-elegant code.  Did you find a way to make it more elegant?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the right syntax (it seems to be working as I expected):

response = xmltodict.parse(xml, force_list=('Child','Brother'))

Just posting in case anyone would look for the same answer in the future.